# How to remove repeated characters at the beginning and at the end of the query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose the query is "xxxxstoryxxxx", how do I remove the preceding 'xxxx' and the succeeding 'xxxx' to make the search query to be "story"?

I tried using regexp `.+++` but it capture non consecutive characters. I also tried using all of the tokenizer, but it still get "xxxxstoryxxxx".
What is the regexp that can be used in this case? or if is there another way to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you index without repeated characters instead of using Regex in research time? You will gain performance

Comment: However, if I understand correctly, I still need to use Regex at the index time whether by using the pattern tokenizer or char_filter.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend read about Character filters  
[Pattern replace character](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html)
 and tokenizer [pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html)

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "type": "pattern",
    "pattern": "x"
  },
  "text": [
    "xxxxstoryxxxx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if I want to implement this with any character? I have tried pattern: "^(((.)\\3+))" but it removes only the preceding, e.g., if text = "xxxxstoryxxxx" then my result is "storyxxxx"